# How to know if email spoofing is successful?

Tags: email, spoofing

Just for knowledge purposes, I want to know if it is possible to know if email spoofing has been done successful or not .  Suppose if I am sending an email from one's account, What if receiver doesn't exist? Means will i get any error as a spoofer that receiver doesn't exist and you cant send email .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know for certain, but you can make an educated guess.

First, when sending an email to a non-existent recipient and the recipient's server is configured to report this to the sender (pretty much the default behaviour), this reporting can happen either:

1) During the email transmission. The SMTP conversation with the recipient's server may very well fail at `RCPT TO:` (i.e. when the recipient is specified) or at the end of the `DATA` or `BDAT` commands (i.e. when the email just have been transmitted and the server either acknowledges this or rejects the email). If you receive an 5xx-type response at either stages, or, well, anytime earlier in the conversation, you can be sure the recipient did not get the message. Validation during email transmission is common.

2) After the email transmission. Servers that don't do recipient validation on SMTP level will often accept and queue emails during the transmission, then generate a bounce report (also called a Delivery Status Notification/DSN or Non-Delivery Report/NDR) later and attempt to return it to the original message sender. As you have no access to the mailbox of the original message sender when spoofing, you will have no idea if such bounce report is generated. This method of validation is still fairly common.

Second, you can embed a tracking image in your HTML email to see if the email was *opened*. This works by placing a HTML `<IMG>` element in the email that points to e.g. `http://example.org/tracking-1x1.gif?uuid=<id>`. The idea is that you track whether that image was downloaded. Be aware that virtually all modern email clients will disable downloading images from unknown sources and some action is required from the recipient to enable downloading images.

Third, you can spoof the MIME sender only. Emails have two distinct set of addressee information: the envelope addressees and the MIME addressees. Emails are delivered based on what's written on the envelope, but email clients render the MIME information instead (what's *inside* the envelope). In other words, during the SMTP transmission you may specify a different sender address (`MAIL FROM:` command) from that in the email (`From:` header). The fun part is that bounce reports are sent to the envelope sender address, a.k.a. the `Return-Path`, so if you have access to the envelope sender mailbox, you can receive a bounce report no matter what stage it was rejected. Note that you *will* reveal yourself, either through the mail server logs or through the email header, where the `Return-Path` header will contain the envelope sender address.

Please use the above information for "knowledge purposes" only. Be aware that email spoofing is likely a crime in just about any country.